# Retrofit response code 200 but null body

Tags: retrofit

i'm trying to retrieve one object value from www.reddit.com/.json but unable due to response.body() is NULL although error code is 200, FYI json_feed and data class is in one folder while another folder contain children and data class, Please help out..

Interface

```
public interface RedditAPI {

String Base_URL = "https://www.reddit.com/";

@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@GET(".json")
Call<json_feed> getData();}
```

Main Activity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Base_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    RedditAPI redditapi = retrofit.create(RedditAPI.class);
    Call<json_feed> call = redditapi.getData();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<json_feed>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<json_feed> call, Response<json_feed> response) {

                ArrayList<Children> childrenList =  response.body().getData().getChildren();
                for (int i = 0; i < childrenList.size(); i++) {
                    Log.d("OnResponse Data = \n",
                            "Subreddit   : " + childrenList.get(i).getData().getSubreddit() +
                            "--------------------------------------------------------------\n");

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<json_feed> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "ERROR = " + t.toString());

            }
        });
```

}

json_feed class

```
public class json_feed {
@SerializedName("Data")
@Expose
private Data data;
//below is get, set and return string method
}
```

data class

```
public class Data {
@SerializedName("Children")
@Expose
private ArrayList<Children> children;
//below is get,set and return string
}
```

children class

```
public class Children {
@SerializedName("Data")
@Expose
private Data data;
//below is get,set and return string
}
```

children --> data class

```
public class Data {

@SerializedName("subreddit")
@Expose
private String subreddit;
//below is get,set and return string
}
```

Comment: UPDATE: Problem solved, seems like the object name is not tally, means "Data" should be "data" according to the json response. How foolish i am, hope this would help someone out there.